Addition formula for Weierstrass $\zeta$ for singular cubic curves
Recall the Weierstrass approach to elliptic functions:
let $P_3(x)=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$, with $g_2,g_3$ constants, and
let $\wp$ be the meromorphic solution of
$$
(\wp')^2=P_3(\wp)
$$
with $\wp(z)-1/z^2$ holomorphic near $0$.  Further, let
$\zeta$ solve
$$
\zeta'=-\wp
$$
with $\zeta(z)-1/z$ holomorphic near zero.
When $P_3$ has no repeated roots, $\wp$ is doubly periodic
and one has the following identity of Frobenius and Stickelberger : whenever $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$
$$
(\zeta(z_1)+\zeta(z_2)+\zeta(z_3))^2+\zeta'(z_1)+\zeta'(z_2)+\zeta'(z_3)=0.
$$
See, for example, Whittaker and Watson, section 20.41.
In fact, this identity holds even when $P_3$ has repeated
roots even though $\wp$ is no longer doubly periodic.
Indeed, you can verify it directly using the explicit
formulae for $\zeta$ that can be found in
Erdelyi,
volume 2, section 13.15. (Example: when $g_2=g_3=0$, $\zeta(z)=1/z$.)
My question: is there an a priori proof of the
Frobenius-Stickelberger identity valid for all $P_3$ or,
better, a reference to such a proof?
